# Imin Printer getPrinterStatus() return -1 (Printer not connected or power on)

Tags: javascript, php

> Imin Printer getPrinterStatus() return -1 (Printer not connected or
> power on)

I tried to connect to built-in printer on my iMin device using this code but am I missing something becuase I got status -1 which mean printer not connected or power on according to the document.

```js
var IminPrintInstance = new IminPrinter();
IminPrintInstance.connect().then( async (isConnect) => {
 if (isConnect) {
  IminPrintInstance.initPrinter();
  const status = await IminPrintInstance.getPrinterStatus();
  console.log('Printer status:' + JSON.stringify(status));
  IminPrintInstance.printAndLineFeed();
  IminPrintInstance.printText("Hello");
  IminPrintInstance.printAndLineFeed();
 }
});
```

Document Link : https://oss-sg.imin.sg/docs/en/Printer.html#javascript-api

Comment: `I used this code`...there is no code in your question. Please [edit] your post to provide a [mre] of your specific issue. See also [ask] and the [tour] please.

Comment: Here is my code https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tuOe.png

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of code, data or error messages. This information is text-based. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please [edit] your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: Also please provide the exact error message you receive, and explain if you're using NodeJS, and if so how that relates in any way to PHP

Comment: I just edit the question Is that better sir? The code itself are not error it just that it not connect to the built-in printer that it should be according to the document and when I tried to get the printer status I got printer not connected or power on. The code is written on laravel blade file so I thought it releated to PHP.

Comment: So you are telling us that `isConnect` returns false, is that right?

Comment: `The code is written on laravel blade file so I thought it releated to PHP`...unless creating a [mre] of the issue involves showing some PHP code, then no it's not relevant to tag it.

Comment: Anyway, what seems to be missing is that you haven't told the IMinPrinter class _how_ to connect to the printer. You didn't supply an IP address, or any other connection method. For example in the [downloadable demo code](https://oss-sg.imin.sg/docs/demo/iMinPrinterSDK.zip), it specifies an IP in the constructor e.g. `var IminPrintInstance = new IminPrinter('10.0.21.53');
    IminPrintInstance.connect().then(async (isConnect) => {`

Comment: Or in the [print SDK guide](https://oss-sg.imin.sg/docs/en/JSPrinterSDK.html) it calls an extra function to initialise e.g. `IminPrintInstance.initPrinter(IminPrintInstance.PrintConnectType.SPI);`. I don't know this SDK but just from the documentation those are my thoughts